# Does the Necklace of Adaptation let someone breathe under the surface of liquids other than water?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

If I was wearing a [Necklace of Adaptation](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#necklaceofAdaptation), and jumped in a tank of lamp oil, would I drown, or would I breathe normally just as if I was in an environment specified in the item's description?

P.S. Related but very much *NOT* a dupe:

[Does Water Breathing let someone breathe under the surface of *any* liquid, or just ordinary water?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71581/does-water-breathing-let-someone-breathe-under-the-surface-of-any-liquid-or-j)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would be able to breathe. The effect of the [*necklace of adaptation*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#necklaceofAdaptation)

> wraps the wearer in a shell of fresh air, making him immune to all harmful vapors and gases […] and allowing him to breathe

When it continues to say “even underwater or in a vacuum”, that's what's known as an “elaboration”, a normal part of how English gets used. It doesn't restrict, it clarifies; the “even” as used there is synonymous with “including” in the non-exhaustive sense.

In order to be a restriction it would have to omit the comma and the “even”, which is a very different sentence construction.

In other words, the *necklace*'s effect doesn't care about the environment at all, allowing normal breathing regardless of environment. (Even underwater or in vacuum!)